# PHP scripts repository

Tags: php, repository

i've got a question.
I'ts possible to make a script repository (not svn or git) in php?

I explain it, I want to make an web app, and make some changes, and new features, and install in a localhost machines with a LAMP, and then, when i program a change and upload to a main server, the "clients" detect the changes and alert or automatically download the new changes, like Automatic Updates in Microsoft, MacOS or Linux.

If it is possible, can someone explain to me how i can do it?

Thanks to everyone interested on this.

Best regards, Carlos

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like a task for PEAR (PHP Extension and Application Repository).  [It describes itself](http://pear.php.net/) as "a framework and distribution system for reusable PHP components".

You would need to install a PEAR channel server.  [Pirum](http://www.pirum-project.org/) is probably the simplest.  You would then need to set up your project on the server.

Your client servers would then need to install the PEAR client, add your server as a channel and install the package.  This is all fairly simple and explained in the Pirum docs.

You could then use a cron job to do `pear upgrade packagename` on a regular basis.

Comment: There is any posibility to code manually? I don't want to need to install Pirum on every server I install my code

Comment: @Brookete You'd just need to install PEAR on every server. Many will already have it... Otherwise, I'm sure it wouldn't be hard to knock together some system where your code is on a central server and a cron job downloads it to the client servers on a regular basis.